# CREATING Formula Field

Tags: formula, formula-field

If the time is between 00:00 to 6:00 display "12AM - 6AM" .The field is text field. How do I convert the enter time as text to time from field time__c?

**update:**

Itz text field . Suppose i enter 14.00 in the field then it should display according to the range .

Example : If the time is between 00:00 to 02:59 display "12AM - 3AM" If the time is between 03:00 to 05:59 display "3AM - 6AM"

Comment: Can you please provide more details?

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit confused. Could I confirm this?
It seems like you have a field, which is a text field. You want to enter the time into this field as "12AM - 6 AM". The source field will be , eg, field__c.
Is this correct?

Comment: So I think if I am right. then you have two text fields, one field someone will enter the time in numerical clock mode, eg, 12:00, and a second field which will be a formula field, to display this in text form.... interesting... And it looks like you want it displayed in a range too...

Comment: Yes , you got it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, first of all, let's call field 1 field_1__c and field 2 field_2__c.

field 1 will be a number field (for manual entry of time), and field 2 is text formula field for the display of range of time.

Field_2__c = IF((0.00 <= field_1__c <= 2.59), "12AM - 3AM",
IF((3.00 <= field_1__c <= 5.59), "3AM - 6AM",
IF((6.00 <= field_1__c <= 8.59), "6AM - 9AM",
IF((9.00 <= field_1__c <= 11.59), "9AM - 12PM",
IF((12.00 <= field_1__c <= 14.59), "12PM - 3PM",
IF((15.00 <= field_1__c <= 17.59), "3PM - 6PM",
IF((18.00 <= field_1__c <= 20.59), "6PM - 9PM","9PM - 12AM")))))))

Comment: I see a large number of problems with this though. 
1. because field_1__c is a number field, what if someone fills in a number such as 11.89? How does that work? There is no really easy validation rules to tell a user to fill in decimal points to be below 0.60.
2. What if someone gets lazy, and just puts in a number '2'? what does that mean? how do you define this?

Probably a better solution is to have field_1__c as a datetime field.... let me think about this. 

Could I please check with you that you are not concerned with the date, and all you care about is the time?

Comment: Could I please check with you that you are not concerned with the date, and all you care about is the time?

Comment: Field 1 is also a text field not numeric

Comment: What about bad data entries?

Comment: For example: 1. because field_1__c is a number field, what if someone fills in a number such as 11.89? How does that work? There is no really easy validation rules to tell a user to fill in decimal points to be below 0.60.

Comment: and 2. What if someone gets lazy, and just puts in a number '2'? what does that mean? how do you define this?

Comment: What if we can split the Hours and Minutes into 2 fields, so for example, Hours__c and Minutes__c? Are you OK with splitting fields?

Comment: Because then, you can just look at the Hours__c field as a integer, and the formula becomes this:

Comment: Field_2__c = IF((0 <= Hours__c <= 2), "12AM - 3AM",
IF((3 <= Hours__c <= 5), "3AM - 6AM",
IF((6 <= Hours__c <= 8), "6AM - 9AM",
IF((9 <= Hours__c <= 11), "9AM - 12PM",
IF((12 <= Hours__c <= 14), "12PM - 3PM",
IF((15 <= Hours__c <= 17), "3PM - 6PM",
IF((18 <= Hours__c <= 20), "6PM - 9PM","9PM - 12AM")))))))

Comment: You then just make sure that the Minutes__c field has a maximum of 2 digits, and a validation rule states that the values in Minutes__c must be between 0 and 59.

Comment: @ HI ALL, Field 1 is also a text field not numeric

Comment: My bad. let me think about this...